# Save/update an entity in console command

Tags: symfony

I'm building a CLI application and am trying to save an entity called `Config`.  Here is the `execute()` logic of the command I have created:

```
$name  = $input->getArgument('name');
$value = $input->getArgument('value');
$output->writeln(sprintf('Setting <info>%s</info> to <info>%s</info>...', $name, $value));
$config = new Config;
$config
    ->setName($name)
    ->setValue($value)
;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($config);
$em->flush();
$output->writeln('Success');
```

The problem is that [I'm not in a controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object) so `$this->getDoctrine()` isn't defined.

How can I save an entity while inside of a `ContainerAwareCommand`?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container . Look in the Symfony base controller class if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Entity Manager you can use

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

So

```
$config = new Config;
$config
    ->setName($name)
    ->setValue($value)
;
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em->persist($config);
$em->flush();
```